# Нахождение координат для шестиугольника

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Нужно построить правильный шестиугольник со стороной а.

Задача на WinForms.

Как можно вывести формулу для нахождения координат правильного шестиугольника?

```
int r;
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        r = int(numericUpDown1->Value); // радиус окружности в которую вписываем полигон
        pictureBox1->Refresh();
}

private: System::Void pictureBox1_Paint(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e) {

        int x = 250;// центр полигона(x)
        int y = 250;// центр полигона(y)
        int n = 6; //  число сторон полигона




        e->Graphics->DrawPolygon(Pens::Black, gcnew array<Point>{
                Point(x1,x2)?,
                Point(x.., x..),
                Point(x.., x..),
                Point(x, x),
                Point(x, x),
                Point(x, x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
double a = длина_стороны;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    double angle = pi * i / 3;
    x[i] = cos(angle) * a;
    y[i] = sin(angle) * a;
}
```

Comment: Получается точки будут( x[0],y[0]), ( x[1],y[1]) и тд, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @propane67 Да, все так.

Comment: Как можно с вами связаться?

Comment: @propane67 Никак, спрашивайте здесь.

Comment: За плату некоторые задания можете выполнить?

Comment: @propane67 Не-а.